# Cellbrowser click event on cell

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, event-handling

I can't figure out how I can add a click handler on a cell in a cellbrowser in GWT.
I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815596/adding-double-click-event-in-celltable-cell-gwt) here on StackOverFlow related to my question, but it was for a double click handler. I can't figure out how to add just a normal click handler.

My purpose is when a user clicks on a cell in the cellbrowser it downloads the child notes from a server. I already played around with onBrowserEvent but I could not get it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add a `ClickHandler` like normal because a `Cell` is not a `Widget.`  `AbstractCell` does have some methods that make it convenient for you to handle events, but you have to call its constructor with the names of the events you'd like to listen to.  For instance, you'd pass "click" to the constructor of your cell, override `onBrowserEvent`, and check for "click" events there.

Look at the source for the `ClickableTextCell` to see how Google added click listeners to a cell.

Comment: I tried what you said and I'm not able to do it. When I want to let the constructor know that he has to listen to click events like this: `super("click", "keydown");` Eclipse always gives an error. Is there somewhere online an example? I looked to the ClickAbleTextCell from Google itself and tried to extend the AbstractCell class like Google does with the AbstractSafeHtmlCell but I could not get it worked.

Comment: Ok I found it out how to do it! Thanks for the fast answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your `TreeViewModel`, you give a `SelectionModel` to the returned `NodeInfo`. You can listen for `SelectionChangeEvent`s on the `SelectionModel` (and given your use case, you'll likely use a `NoSelectionModel`, most probably a single one shared by all levels that need that *onclick* behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the the answer. I tried it out and gwt only executes the handler when I use setSelected(object, true); When I select an other cell in the cellbrowser it doesn't executes the code anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is also interesting for other web developers using GWT so this is how I did it:

```
// Create a clickable cell.
            Cell<C> cell = new ClickCell() {
              @Override
              public void render(Context context, C value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                if (value != null) {
                  sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
                }
              }
              @Override
              public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, C value,
                  NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<C> valueUpdater) {
                super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
                if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
                  onEnterKeyDown(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);

                }
              }
            @Override
              protected void onEnterKeyDown(Context context, Element parent, C value,
                  NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<C> valueUpdater) {
                if (valueUpdater != null) {
                  valueUpdater.update(value);
                }
              }
            };
```

And this is the class ClickCell that extends the AbstractCell class:

```
public abstract class ClickCell extends AbstractCell<C> {

    public ClickCell() {
        super("click", "keydown");
    }
}
```