# How to capture doubleClickEvent in GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, double-click, celltable

I'm trying to make a GWT `CellTable` catch events of type `DoubleClickEvent`, but while the `CellTable` correctly receives events of type `ClickEvent` when a row is clicked in the UI, it not see any `DoubleClickEvent` when the row is double-clicked.

So, if I click a row in the UI, the handler declared for `ClickEvent` is correctly triggered, but if I double click the handler declared for `DoubleClickEvent` is *not* triggered, instead.

Am I doing something wrong or `CellTable` itself cannot handle `DoubleClickEvent` at all?
In the latter case, what could be a good way to capture double-clicks in a table?

Below, the code for my CellTable declaration:

```
CellTable<ServiceTypeUI> contentTable = new CellTable<ServiceTypeUI>(10, style);
contentTable.setSelectionModel(new SingleSelectionModel<ServiceTypeUI>());
contentTable.addHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() { // HANDLER NOT CORRECTLY TRIGGERED
   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
       presenter.doubleClickHandler(event);
   }

}, DoubleClickEvent.getType());
contentTable.addHandler(new ClickHandler() { // HANDLER CORRECTLY TRIGGERED
   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
       presenter.clickHandler(event);
   }

}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

I've also tried removing `ClickEvent` handler declaration and the `SelectionModel` declaration, to avoid that any of those capture the `DoubleClickEvent` event and treat it as a `ClickEvent` but the DoubleClickHandler has not been triggered even in this case.

```
CellTable<ServiceTypeUI> contentTable = new CellTable<ServiceTypeUI>(10, style);
contentTable.addHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() { // HANDLER NOT CORRECTLY TRIGGERED
   @Override
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
       presenter.doubleClickHandler(event);
   }

}, DoubleClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815596/adding-double-click-event-in-celltable-cell-gwt

Comment: It's not a duplicate, that question is about the single cell event handler, not the table handler. I read that before posting my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
       SingleSelectionModel<T> selectionModel
     = new SingleSelectionModel<T>();

   cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
   cellTable.addDomHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event) {
            T selected = selectionModel
                    .getSelectedObject();
            if (selected != null) {
                //DO YOUR STUFF

                                  }

        }
    }, 
    DoubleClickEvent.getType());
```

You have to replace the T with the your "ServiceTypeUI" . The value selected will be the object which was been chosen from the user.