# Double Click event for DataGrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid, double-click

I added double click event for DataGrid, but it doesn't work correctly. The code handles a single click, but it does *not* handle double click.

Please help.

```
private DataGrid<Contract> table = new DataGrid<Contract>();
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Contract>() {
  @Override
  public void onCellPreview(final CellPreviewEvent<Contract> event) {
    if (BrowserEvents.DBLCLICK.equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
      //it doesn't handle
      Window.alert("Tro-lo-lo");
    }
    if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
      //it handles
      Window.alert("Tru-la-la");        
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to replace alerts with `console.log`. Alert may block your second click.

Comment: I had replaced WIndow.alert by the logging and I saw that when I do double click it handles as 2 clicks.

Comment: Please suggest me something.

Comment: `DataGrid` has many things in common with `CellTable`. So I think solutions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815596/adding-double-click-event-in-celltable-cell-gwt) must work for you too.

Comment: It helped me. I really appreciate you. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGrid has many things in common with CellTable. So solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815596/adding-double-click-event-in-celltable-cell-gwt) must work for you too:

- Using `CellPreviewHandler` count time between two clicks
- Or you can add `DoubleClickHandler` using `addDomHandler` method

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGrid.addDomHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) { 
        DataGrid<YourDataProviderType> grid = (DataGrid<YourDataProviderType>) event.getSource();
        int row = grid.getKeyboardSelectedRow();
        YourDataProviderType item = grid.getVisibleItem(row);
        Window.alert("Do Something Here");
    }    
}, DoubleClickEvent.getType());
```