# Double click event not working- DataGrid - GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, datagrid, event-handling

I am having an issue implementing a double click handler for my Datagrid. I have found a solution posted on Stack overflow that should fix my problem i believe, however, I can not figure out:

```
1. How exactly do I implement it?
2. What is <T>?
```

I am getting various errors I do not understand. The issue is almost certainly with the way I add the CellPreviewHandler (Line 6)

**Errors** (line 6 & 8)

-the Type new CellPreviewEvent.Handler(){} must implement the inherited abstract method CellPreviewEvent.Handler.onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent)

-The method onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent) of type new AsynCallBack(String[][]>(){} must override or implement a supertype method

**MyCode:**

```
Public Class DataGrid extends Widget{
    Timer singleClickTimer;
    int clickCount = 0;
    int clickDelay = 300;
myDataTable = new DataGrid<String[]>(result.length, resources, KEY_PROVIDER);
myDataTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<T>(){
@Override
public void onCellPreview(final CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
    if (Event.getTypeInt(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) == Event.ONMOUSEOVER) {
        handleOnMouseOver(event);
    } else if (Event.getTypeInt(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) == Event.ONCLICK) {
        clickCount++;
        if (clickCount == 1) {
            singleClickTimer = new Timer() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    clickCount = 0;
                    handleOnClick(event);
                }
            };
            singleClickTimer.schedule(clickDelay);
        } else if (clickCount == 2) {
            singleClickTimer.cancel();
            clickCount = 0;
            handleOnDblClick(event);
        }
    }
}
});
private void handleOnMouseOver(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
    Element cell = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
    GWT.log("mouse over event");
}

private void handleOnClick(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
    Element cell = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
    GWT.log("click event");
}

private void handleOnDblClick(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
    Element cell = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();            
    GWT.log("double click event");
}
```

Link to original solution:
[adding Double click event in CellTable cell - GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815596/adding-double-click-event-in-celltable-cell-gwt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very good code (a better option would be to extend DataGrid class), but if you don't want to change much, simply replace `<T>` with `<String[]>`.

Comment: Yes the DataGrid class was created by another developer that is not currently available to consult with. Obviously since my datagrid has already been implemented and currently works (minus the double click handler) I can't change too much of it... so where does that leave me with possible solutions for a double click handler?

Comment: Ok i got it, thanks a lot! Still not sure what this <T> means though for future knowledge :/

Comment: Java Generic Types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html